# Subscribe to wall posts objects through realtime updates

Tags: facebook-graph-api, real-time, subscription, updates, posts

On the realtime updates page they said that we were not **YET** allowed to subscribe to posts objects and to check back in the future for further expansions.
Actually, those lines of text has disappeared and I can't seem to find them anywhere nor notes about those lines being removed.

Anyone knows anything about this subject?

Comment: I can't really tell what your question is.  What are you really trying to find out and what are you trying to achieve?  Post some links to what you're talking about or specify a problem you're having.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not supported. The Realtime Updates API constrains the subscription types to only 5 types, and posts are not one of them.

(That said, Facebook is always interested to know what additional services developers might be interested in)

Comment: Yes, I know it is actually not supported. But since a few weeks ago they were supposely planning that realtime posts subscribtion was planned in the future. It now seems that the subject has been completely discarded.

Comment: Ops, new to this place and <enter> did send the comment. Is there a place where I could directly question someone of the developer team or does anyone know about their plans for further expansions of the realtime API?

Comment: We don't make commitments about future functionality but I realize there are many other use cases for realtime updates. Have noted this suggestion.